# What is different nami wallet signing and payment.skey signing?

Tags: blockchain, cardano, plutus

I built transaction at nodejs by using cardano-cli.

```
cardano-cli transaction build \
--alonzo-era \
--testnet-magic 1 \
--tx-in dbf7f56f844cc4b85daccb62bedf4eeff0a84cb060f0f79b206c7f087b3f0ba1#0 \
--tx-in dbf7f56f844cc4b85daccb62bedf4eeff0a84cb060f0f79b206c7f087b3f0ba1#1  \
--tx-in 61b88efd41ccbb0e71c48aca2cbe63728078ec7fb20ec9c27acfe33d0647248d#0 \
--tx-in-script-file /cardano/plutus/direct-sale.plutus \
--tx-in-datum-file /cardano/temp/testnet/datums/list.json \
--tx-in-redeemer-file /cardano/temp/testnet/redeemers/buy.json \
--required-signer-hash 2be4a303e36f628e2a06d977e16f77ce2b9046b8c56576bb5286d1be \
--tx-in-collateral dbf7f56f844cc4b85daccb62bedf4eeff0a84cb060f0f79b206c7f087b3f0ba1#1 \

... some txout ...

--change-address addr_test1qq47fgcrudhk9r32qmvh0ct0wl8zhyzxhrzk2a4m22rdr0sqcga2xfzv6crryyt0sfphksfr947jjddy3t4u0qwfmmfq2h0pj8 \
--protocol-params-file /cardano/testnet/protocol-parameters.json \
--mint "2 20edea925974af2102c63adddbb6a6e789f8d3a16500b15bd1e1c32b.4143544956495459" \
--mint-script-file /cardano/plutus/activity-minter.plutus \
--mint-redeemer-file /cardano/redeemers/mint.json \
--invalid-before 19059345 \
--invalid-hereafter 19059495 \
--out-file ./tx.raw
```

After run this command, I got cborHex and I used this at frontend.
When I sign by using name wallet, I got some error.

```
"transaction submit error ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraBabbage (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (FromAlonzoUtxowFail (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (InvalidWitnessesUTXOW [VKey (VerKeyEd25519DSIGN \"cf949f966b426f25db11b6062edc31312001e3cd0ced4c6c7db3da7b5ac9766b\")])))])"
```

But when I sign with payment.skey at nodejs, it was worked.
I was discuss **Alexd1985** at cardano forum.

https://forum.cardano.org/t/how-to-resolve-shelleytxvalidationerror-shelleybasederababbage-applytxerror-utxowfailure-fromalonzoutxowfail-wrappedshelleyerafailure-invalidwitnessesutxow-error/113555/4

What is solution for this problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://cardano.stackexchange.com/ and it unrelated to Haskell

Comment: anyway, if you know the solution, provide it for comunity. don't just criticize.
Are you finding happy from criticize?

Comment: I am not criticizing. actually I've kindly pointed you to the right place to ask. This cuestion is unrelated to software development. It is about a tool/ecosystem which has its own stackexchange place.